# psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation error handling , where to add the try except block

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

I'm getting these error , can anyone tell me in which code block i should put try except code for handling the psycopg2 UniqueViolation error?
I have tried putting the try except in lines :

> 1.sfm_ui_consumer.py", line 112
> 2.models.py", line 607

> 3.models.py", line 79, in history_save

But this is not catching the error,

can anyone help where i should put the try except code block for handling the psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint?

```
EBUG 2022-10-06 09:53:43,747 1 ui.rabbit Declaring sfm_exchange exchange
DEBUG 2022-10-06 09:53:44,037 1 ui.config Setting receivers for collections.
DEBUG 2022-10-06 09:53:44,038 1 ui.config Setting receiver for exports.
DEBUG 2022-10-06 09:53:44,038 1 ui.config Not running scheduler
DEBUG 2022-10-06 09:53:44,038 1 ui.config Setting delete receivers
DEBUG 2022-10-06 09:53:44,038 1 ui.config Setting collection receivers
INFO 2022-10-06 09:53:45,955 1 message_consumer.sfm_ui_consumer Updating harvest with id 44477b7d22164d78a4b6375ca924f06b: completed success
INFO 2022-10-06 09:55:42,729 1 message_consumer.sfm_ui_consumer Updating harvest with id 793a8a9d9fda4655a738a16ecb4e8462: running
DEBUG 2022-10-06 09:55:51,497 1 message_consumer.sfm_ui_consumer Warc with id d7b068dc965f43bf915a79ae1f1158d3
INFO 2022-10-06 09:55:52,571 1 message_consumer.sfm_ui_consumer Updating harvest with id 793a8a9d9fda4655a738a16ecb4e8462: running
ERROR 2022-10-06 09:55:52,579 1 message_consumer.sfm_ui_consumer duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ui_seed_collection_id_uid_token_744a7e90_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (collection_id, uid, token)=(15, 34743251, SpaceX) already exists.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ui_seed_collection_id_uid_token_744a7e90_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (collection_id, uid, token)=(15, 34743251, SpaceX) already exists.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/sfm-ui/sfm/message_consumer/sfm_ui_consumer.py", line 47, in on_message
    self._on_harvest_status_message()
  File "/opt/sfm-ui/sfm/message_consumer/sfm_ui_consumer.py", line 112, in _on_harvest_status_message
    seed.save()
  File "/opt/sfm-ui/sfm/ui/models.py", line 613, in save
    return history_save(self, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/sfm-ui/sfm/ui/models.py", line 82, in history_save
    return super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 743, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 780, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 853, in _save_table
    updated = self._do_update(base_qs, using, pk_val, values, update_fields,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 903, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 760, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1471, in execute_sql
    cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1142, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ui_seed_collection_id_uid_token_744a7e90_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (collection_id, uid, token)=(15, 34743251, SpaceX) already exists.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ui_seed_collection_id_uid_token_744a7e90_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (collection_id, uid, token)=(15, 34743251, SpaceX) already exists.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 624, in _receive_callback
    return on_m(message) if on_m else self.receive(decoded, message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 590, in receive
    [callback(body, message) for callback in callbacks]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 590, in <listcomp>
    [callback(body, message) for callback in callbacks]
  File "/opt/sfm-utils/sfmutils/consumer.py", line 111, in _callback
    self.on_message()
  File "/opt/sfm-ui/sfm/message_consumer/sfm_ui_consumer.py", line 57, in on_message
    raise e
  File "/opt/sfm-ui/sfm/message_consumer/sfm_ui_consumer.py", line 47, in on_message
    self._on_harvest_status_message()
  File "/opt/sfm-ui/sfm/message_consumer/sfm_ui_consumer.py", line 112, in _on_harvest_status_message
    seed.save()
  File "/opt/sfm-ui/sfm/ui/models.py", line 613, in save
    return history_save(self, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/sfm-ui/sfm/ui/models.py", line 82, in history_save
    return super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 743, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 780, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 853, in _save_table
    updated = self._do_update(base_qs, using, pk_val, values, update_fields,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 903, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 760, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1471, in execute_sql
    cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1142, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ui_seed_collection_id_uid_token_744a7e90_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (collection_id, uid, token)=(15, 34743251, SpaceX) already exists.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/sfm-ui/sfm/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/sfm-ui/sfm/message_consumer/management/commands/startconsumer.py", line 20, in handle
    consumer.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/mixins.py", line 175, in run
    for _ in self.consume(limit=None, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/mixins.py", line 197, in consume
    conn.drain_events(timeout=safety_interval)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/librabbitmq/__init__.py", line 227, in drain_events
    self._basic_recv(timeout)
SystemError: <method '_basic_recv' of '_librabbitmq.Connection' objects> returned a result with an error set
```

Comment: You left the important part which is an example of the code you have tried. **Do not use an image**, copy and paste the code into your question.

Comment: You have added the traceback which just confirms what you already said that you are getting `.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint` and is not really that important. What is the important is the actual code you run in the application that triggers this error.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is showing the issue
**django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ui_seed_collection_id_uid_token_744a7e90_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (collection_id, uid, token)=(15, 34743251, SpaceX) already exists.**
You are saving an object which is already present in the database which is unique and you are saving it again

Kindly show your where you are saving the object

Comment: def save(self, *args, **kw):
        try:
            return history_save(self, *args, **kw)
        except UniqueViolation as err:
            log.error("uplicate key value violates unique constraint")

Comment: This is where save function is defined

Comment: Can you please tell e where i should add the try except block looking the errors?

Comment: If you have    sfm_ui_consumer.py", line 112.  
try putting it here and try to write **except Exception as err ** instead of **UniqueViolation** But why are you looking to make a try catch rather than solving the problem .